# c# hidden input not populating on page load when failed

Tags: c#, html, webforms

Very odd one this - when i run some code on page_load and it fails, i want to populate a hidden text box with a value. The code fires and steps through in debug but the value still turns out blank. The code runs fine and hits this:

```
if (strResults[0] != "Success") {
fail.Value = "Failed";

}
```

so fail's value should say "Failed" if the submit was a failure (Success if it worked) but it doesn't.

Here' the code (edited)

```
try {
        if (Request.QueryString["bla"] != null) {
            if (Request.QueryString["blabla"] == "yes")

        }

        if (Request.QueryString["blablablabla"] != null) {
            if (Request.QueryString["bla"] == "yes") {
                string strResponse = "";
                try {
                    if ());

                        if (intTransactionCodeAlreadyExists > 0) {
                        } else {
                            //do stuff
                            );

                            string[] strResults = strResponse.Split('|');

                            if (strResults[0] != "Success") {
                                fail.Value = "Failed";

                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                   //do stuff
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is `fail`? How is it bound to your View?

Comment: @RyanWilson it's purely a hidden field - <input type="hidden" id="fail" runat="server" />

Comment: Is this webforms, MVC, something else?

Comment: right, `runat="server"` means webforms. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: how do u set the value of `strResponse`?

Comment: `strResponse` is literally never set, your instanciate it `string strResponse = "";` and then try and split it `strResponse.Split('|');` obviously this isn't going to do anything... Simply debugging your code would of made this obvious.

Comment: @Liam there's `//do stuff` comment. i assume Ben's assigning it there

Comment: @DanielB is correct - i'm setting the strResponse in the //do stuff part. The actual problem i am getting is when this comes back as failed, it runs through this if (strResults[0] != "Success") and works but just doesn't action any code/function within the if statement. It's most bizarre! I was hoping someone else might have had a similar issue and had some pointers where the issue is.

Comment: @BenWilliams better you upload both aspx and cs file somewhere to better help u.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit messed up in my setup. After a re-install of visual studio, the code started working as expected. Not 100% sure what the issue was here but all fixed. Thanks for the help.